# How to get the RECENT records first?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

MySQL code: jsfiddle.net/HBps8/

I have a table called "Likers", in that table, there is "**ID**, User FB ID, user FB name, and user Access Token".
At the moment, there are 2487 records in the "Likers" table.

(**ID** is the number of user, if the user submitted his access token when the table was EMPTIED; his ID will be 1, if another user submits his access token after the first user; his id will be 2 and so on and on)

The problem I am facing is that when the HTML form is submitted to get the IDs; it gets the OLDEST ids first (ID #1, #2, #3, #4, etc...)
What I want is that when the form is submitted, the RECENT ID's should be first (ID #2487, #2486, #2485, #2484, etc...)

Is it possible to do something like that in MySQL database? I am very new to the databases codes and I am trying my best to learn :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MySQL query you can use ORDER BY

For example

```
SELECT * FROM `Likers` ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

Comment: Hi, what does the "DESC" mean/do ?

Comment: @user3213765 descending and ascending, could alternatively use ASC for ascending. Determines how the results are ordered based on the field given (ID)

Answer (score 1):

you can sort the result by using `ORDER BY`, e.g. `ORDER BY ID DESC`. But it is not recommended to determine the latest entries by the ID, you should add a additional field like `creationDate` and sort by this one.